# How can I disable auto scrolling in gnome terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

When I enter a command with a long output such as `locate linux`, the output is too long to show on the current terminal screen, and so the terminal will scroll right to the end of the output. How can I disable this behavior, such that window stays on the first line of the output?

Alternatively, is there a way to get the window back to the last `$` line without having to actually look for where that line is?

I have tried `Edit > Profile Preferences > Scrolling` and disabling `Scroll on output`, although this does not achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, at least not exactly the way you want.

More useful answer: you can achieve what you want by piping the output to something like `more` or `less` , for example :

```
locate linux | less
```

This will pause the output scroll at the end of each page, where the page length is defined as the terminal height.

Comment: Alright, I found that using `less -X` achieves close to the feature I am looking for, such that the output remains in the terminal after exiting.

Comment: @jII You will need to scroll all the way to the bottom if you want `less -X` to leave all the output on the terminal. Also, if scroll both up and down, you will leave duplicate lines in the output. Try experimenting with `seq 1 1000 | less -X`

Comment: If you want to preserve colours, you need to tell `less` to display colour by passing through colour escape sequences using `-R`, and you need to tell the program that you are running to always display colours even when the output is piped. For example: `ls --color=always | less -R`